# Autostart supervisord 4.0.0, Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, autostart, supervisord

I installed last version from https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor
By command:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Now I'm able to run supervisord manually, just by typing

```
sudo supervisord
```

So, after this all my process are working well with `supervisorctl`

My question is: how to run `supervisord` just after reboot?
I want all my scripts, defined in `supervisorctl` starts after start of the system.

Solution is:
add `supervisord &` at /etc/rc.local

Comment: Google "how to run linux program at startup"

Answer (score 0):

To run supervisord automatically on startup , use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable supervisor.service
```